# Attaching the windows debugger in VS2010 from a batch file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, batch-file

Is it possible to attach the windows debugger in VS2010 to a process from a batch file?

preferably by giving it a process name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the debugging tools for windows available, the `tlist.exe` utility will yield the process ID for a process name.  If that is available, then the following will attach to a given process:

```
rem Get the process ID
for /f %%f in ('tlist -p %1') do set mypid=%%f
rem attach to it with selected debugger
vsjitDebugger -p %mypid%
```

**Edit** If `tlist` is not available, I think tasklist will work.  It's a bit uglier, but the following worked for me (you know ... it works my on my system :)  Note too that I edited the command previous example to work in a cmd.exe prompt (I use tcc, which does require as many `%` signs).

```
rem Get the process ID
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%f in ('tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq %1"' ) do set mypid=%%f
rem attach to it with selected debugger
vsjitDebugger -p %mypid%
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you presumably already have the process running, you would use `vsjitdebugger.exe /p 1234` where 1234 is the PID of the process you want to debug. If you don't know it, you would have to use some other method to figure it out.

Comment: I Googled this and I found out that it's located in Windows/System32/. It's just what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2):

Specifying a /Command switch on devenv.exe 's command-line will make it run a specified command on open. You could specify the Debug.AttachToProcess command. Don't know if you can specify a pid, though, when you execute that command.